# Passing arguments to next screen using routes, result in pageIndex 0 instead of 1

Tags: flutter

#### **Sending Code:**

```
onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(
                        context,
                        RouteName.selectLanguageScreen,
                        arguments: {'pageIndex': 1},
                      );
                    }
```

#### **Receiving Code** :

```
final dynamic data;
// class constructor
  const ClassName({
    super.key,
    this.data = const {},
  });
```

```
final pageIndex = widget.data['pageIndex'] ?? 0;
```

```
print("pageIndex");
```

**Output:**

```
0
```

I've verified that the route name RouteName.selectLanguageScreen is correct. I'm not sure why the argument value isn't being passed correctly.